# CROSS JOIN and STDistance to find closest point

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables with Walmart locations, and I want to know which Walmart from one table is closest to the Walmart of the other location.

This would be the result, if possible:

```
Source        ClosestToSource       DistanceInMeters
-----------------------------------------------------
Walmart1      Walmart8              2637.37
Walmart2      Walmart5              2047.19
Walmart3      Walmart8              1191.31
Walmart4      Walmart7              3340.33
```

This is basically saying that the closest Walmart for *Walmart1* in `@Source` is *Walmart8* in `@Dest`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WSource', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.WSource; 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WDest', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.WDest; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.WSource
(
    Id int IDENTITY,
    StoreName varchar(15),
    Lat float,
    Lon float,
    GeoLocation geography
)

CREATE TABLE WDest
(
    Id int IDENTITY,
    StoreName varchar(15),
    Lat float,
    Lon float,
    GeoLocation geography
)

INSERT INTO WSource (StoreName, Lat, Lon)
select 'Walmart1', 28.064924, -81.652854 union
select 'Walmart2', 28.073512, -81.655092 union
select 'Walmart3', 28.063939, -81.665558 union
select 'Walmart4', 28.061616, -81.630152

update WSource
set geolocation = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Lon AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                    CAST(Lat AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)


insert into WDest (StoreName, Lat, Lon)
select 'Walmart5', 28.078024, -81.675264 union
select 'Walmart6', 28.079128, -81.693943 union
select 'Walmart7', 28.089832, -81.642243 union
select 'Walmart8', 28.062409, -81.677583

update WDest
set geolocation = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(Lon AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                    CAST(Lat AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)

SELECT WSource.geolocation.STDistance(WDest.geolocation)
FROM WSource
CROSS JOIN WDest
```

This shows all the distances from one location to the other, but that's where I got stuck. I was thinking of using `RANK()` function, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Based on the results above, the closest to *Walmart2* is *Walmart5*, but not sure how to implement it.

Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is described in the docs: [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-ver16). Spatial querying without a spatial index is pointless. The query needs to satisfy the requirement otherwise it won't be able to use the index.

Comment: What is the actual, realistic problem you want to solve? You can't calculate the distance without comparing it to all stored points. Real GIS systems don't just look for the nearest point(s), they limit the search area in a box first.

Answer (score 1):

One option is an `APPLY` with a `TOP (1)`.

```sql
SELECT
  WSource.StoreName AS Source,
  WDest.StoreName AS ClosestToSource,
  WDest.DistanceToSource
FROM WSource
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      WDest.*,
      WDest.geolocation.STDistance(WSource.geolocation) AS DistanceToSource
    FROM WDest
    WHERE WDest.geolocation.STDistance(WSource.geolocation) AS DistanceToSource IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY DistanceToSource
) WDest;
```

You can also use ranking functions

```sql
SELECT
  w.*
FROM (
    SELECT
      WSource.StoreName AS Source,
      WDest.StoreName AS ClosestToSource,
      WDest.geolocation.STDistance(WSource.geolocation) AS DistanceToSource,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WSource.Id ORDER BY WDest.geolocation.STDistance(WSource.geolocation)) AS rn
    FROM WSource
    CROSS JOIN WDest
    WHERE WDest.geolocation.STDistance(WSource.geolocation) IS NOT NULL
) w
WHERE w.rn = 1;
```

The performance difference would probably depend on whether you had a supporting Spatial Index: the former will perform very well if so, but very badly if not.

You may also want to check if it's faster calculating the distance from Source to Dest or vice versa.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6mEhHT5P)

Comment: None of these options will use spatial indexes. [The requirements for nearest neighbor queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-ver16) are pretty strict. You can't calculate the distance without scanning every row either, so the optimizer will have to perform some extra tricks to limit the number of rows to scan

Comment: To be honest, the spatial indexes ain't that great in sql server, I'd be willing to say hitting the index usually makes the query worse. You can use haversine formula to calculate the distance instead and save yourself the headache

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Looks like it was just missing a `IS NOT NULL` predicate and swapping the source and dest, but I admit I haven't tried it.